# How to fit an AlertDialog size to the image that contains

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-alertdialog, android-image

I'm trying to create a AlertDialog which will show an image in fullscreen. My problem is that the dialog does not fit the image.
I could scale the image to fit the horizontal or vertical limit (depending on the screen oreintation) with some code that I found. However , the dialog shows an empty space that I want eliminate.

My dialog shows this:

[image]

But I want that it fits the image without the left and right empty space, like this:
[image]

My code to create the alert dialog:

```
void showImage(String path, String name) {

    // Get image from the aboslute path
    BitmapDrawable bitmap = new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), path);

    // Construct the dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    imageDialog.setTitle(name);
    imageDialog.setCancelable(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thumbnail, null);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
    imageDialog.setView(layout);
    imageAlert = imageDialog.create();

    // Fullscreen
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    lp.copyFrom(imageAlert.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    lp.height = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    imageAlert.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    image.setMinimumWidth(lp.width);
    image.setMinimumHeight(lp.height);

    imageAlert.show();
}
```

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried `scaleType = fitXY`, but it deforms the image.
How can I make the dialog fit the image keeping the same aspect ratio? Any help would be appreciate

I could find a way to solve my problem, but I dont know if its the best way to do it. I calculated the image size manually and set the image and dialog to this size. 
First, I check which dimesion will limit the size of the image, and set the screen value to that dimesion. Then, I calculated the other dimesion in relation to the previous to keep the same ratio and the image is not deformed.

```
    // Get screen size
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;
    int screenHeight = size.y;

    // Get image size
    int imgHeight = bitmap.getBitmap().getHeight();
    int imgWidth = bitmap.getBitmap().getWidth();

    // Get dialog params
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(imageAlert.getWindow().getAttributes());

    // Which dimension is bigger in relation to screen size
    if (((float)imgHeight) / screenHeight > ((float)imgWidth) / screenWidth) {

        // Height is bigger so width is calculated on relation to it to keep the same ratio
        lp.height = screenHeight;
        lp.width = (int) (imgWidth * ((float) screenHeight) / imgHeight);
    }
    else {
        // Width is bigger so height is calculated on relation to it to keep the same ratio
        lp.height =(int) (imgHeight * ((float) screenWidth) / imgWidth);
        lp.width = screenWidth;
    }

    // Set the new size
    image.getLayoutParams().width = lp.width;
    image.getLayoutParams().height = lp.height;
    image.requestFocus();
    imageAlert.show();

    imageAlert.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for imageview.

Comment: I tried, but it changes the aspect ratio of the image, i can't deform it

Comment: Change height and width of your parent layout and imageview to match_parent.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't change how the image is shown

Comment: try adding liner layout with background instead of imageview.

Comment: It happens the same, the image is scaled to fit the width and height and is deformed

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
imageDialog.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: imageDialog doesn't have the methode setLayoutParams. Is there other way to set them?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);` and also make height and width match_parent as shown below:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It works when the orientation is LANDSCAPE, but when I switch to portrait I can only see a piece of the image. Is there a way to see the full image?